# Can I purchase religious items from Rome to resell at my business in the US? Am I limited on how much (value of the products) that I can bring?

Tags: business-travel, import-taxes

I own a religious store in the United States and will be traveling to Rome for my wedding anniversary with my husband. I want to take advantage of being there and shop for items I can sell in my store. Am I able to do bring those items with me in our carry on bags or checked in suitcases? Is there a dollar amount limit as to how much I can bring?

Comment: Not sure about the US, but in most countries tax-free allowances are for items for personal use only, so you would need to declare everything from the first cent. Imports duties are a complex topic, and customs usually prefer when this is handled by specialised companies rather than just when going through customs at the airport. But in any case you would be better off purchasing from manufacturers at wholesale prices and having them shipped to you rather than buying in stores and carrying them back yourself.

Comment: You can bring as much as you want, you just have to declare it and pay import duty on it. You may also be able to to get the VAT you pay in Italy refunded when you export the items. I would familiarize myself with the paper work first.